TempData not displaying message after successful creation in ASP.NET MVC and can't edit by id as TempData is not holding the data
The problem is when the category is created successfully, then it is only loading the progress animation of toastr.js but not showing the message, but If I uncomment the TempData["success"] or TempData["error"] in index.cshtml, then it is working for index.cshtml, but as I created a partial view for that so I keep the partial view in _Layout.cshtml, but it is only showing animation but not loading the message, and I can't also edit the data in index.cshtml by TempData as it is not holding the id.
In POS Software\POS Software\Areas\Admin\Controllers\CategoryController:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using POS.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using POS.Models;

namespace POS_Software.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    [Area("Admin")]
    public class CategoryController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public CategoryController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Category> objCategoryList = _unitOfWork.Category.GetAll().ToList();
            return View(objCategoryList);
        }

        // GET: Upsert action to prepare the modal for edit or creation
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Upsert(Guid? id)
        {
            Category category = new Category();

            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                category = _unitOfWork.Category.Get(c => c.Id == id.Value);
                if (category == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }

            // Store the retrieved category or new category in TempData
            TempData["CategoryId"] = category.Id;
            TempData["CategoryName"] = category.CategoryName;

            // Redirect to Index to open the modal with the data
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        // POST: Upsert action for creation or update
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(Category category)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine($"CategoryName: {category.CategoryName}");
            //Console.WriteLine($"CategoryId: {category.Id}");

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
                //{
                //    var state = ModelState[key];
                //    foreach (var error in state.Errors)
                //    {
                //        Console.WriteLine($"Error in '{key}': {error.ErrorMessage}");
                //    }
                //}
                TempData["error"] = "Invalid category data. Please check the inputs.";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            if (category.Id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                category.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                category.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                _unitOfWork.Category.Add(category);
                TempData["success"] = "Category created successfully.";
            }
            else
            {
                var existingCategory = _unitOfWork.Category.Get(c => c.Id == category.Id);

                if (existingCategory == null)
                {
                    TempData["error"] = "Category not found.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                existingCategory.CategoryName = category.CategoryName;
                _unitOfWork.Category.Update(existingCategory);
                TempData["success"] = "Category updated successfully.";
            }

            _unitOfWork.Save();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}

In POS Software\POS Software\Views\Shared\_Notification.cshtml:
@if (TempData["success"] != null)
{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        toastr.options = {
            "progressBar": true
        };
        toastr.success('@TempData["success"]');
    </script>
}

@if (TempData["error"] != null)
{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        toastr.options = {
            "progressBar": true
        };
        toastr.error('@TempData["error"]');
    </script>
}

In POS Software\POS Software\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:
<div class="container-fluid pt-4 px-4">
    <div class="row g-4">
        <partial name="_Notification" />
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>

In POS Software\POS Software\Areas\Admin\Views\Category\Index.cshtml:
@model IEnumerable<POS.Models.Category>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Categories Data</h5>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Upsert", "Category")" class="btn btn-primary" style="box-shadow: none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#categoryModal">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> &nbsp;Add Category
            </a>

            <!-- Modal for Create/Update Category -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="categoryModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="categoryModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" method="post">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="categoryModalLabel">
                                    @if (TempData["CategoryId"] != null)
                                    {
                                        <span>Edit Category</span>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <span>Add New Category</span>
                                    }
                                </h5>
                                <button type="button" style="box-shadow: none" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <!-- Hidden Field for Id -->
                                <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="@(TempData["CategoryId"] ?? Guid.Empty.ToString())" />


                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="CategoryName" class="form-label fw-bold ms-1">Category Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CategoryName" name="CategoryName"
                                           value="@TempData["CategoryName"]" required placeholder="Category Name" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Success/Error Messages -->
        @* @if (TempData["success"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success">@TempData["success"]</div>
        }

        @if (TempData["error"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger">@TempData["error"]</div>
        } *@

        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th>S/N</th>
                        <th>Category Name</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{
                        int index = 1;
                    }

                    @foreach (var category in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@index</td>
                            <td>@category.CategoryName</td>
                            <td>@category.CreatedAt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Upsert", "Category", new { id = category.Id })"
                                   class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#categoryModal">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        index++;
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Not showing the message after successful creation:

And I click on Edit, it is not showing the category name:


Can you try print simple JavaScript alert or console.log? Weather its working or not. Just to check if toaster plugin working  correctly or not.

A tip for you - never use TempData. TempData is antithetical to the stateless nature of web apps.

Hi @Maruf Hasnat, Your issue here is not the TempData does not persist the value, your anchor link even does not hit the backend code, it just trigger the Bootstrap default js code to pop up the modal. Two ways you could achieve your requirement. One way is to use the default Bootstrap js to pop up the modal, you need add the modal html for each button. The second way I think it is better for performance it to reuse the modal as the partial view and use ajax to call Upsert action to render the partial view as the response.

1.TempData in Partial Views: TempData is typically used to store data for the next request, but it might not work seamlessly with partial views because partial views don't trigger a full request cycle. In this case, the TempData values are not getting carried over to the partial view as expected.
2.Toastr.js Message Not Displaying: Since the animation is showing but no message is being rendered, it likely indicates that the JavaScript code is not properly handling or displaying the message content.
3.Unable to Edit Data in Index.cshtml with TempData: TempData is not persisting the ID properly for your edits in Index.cshtml, which may point to an issue with how data is passed or how the page lifecycle works with partial views.


And I click on Edit, it is not showing the category name

You may misunderstand the usage of bootstrap modal. What you did even do not hit the Upsert HttpGet action. Just always trigger the modal with empty value with default bootstrap js.
A whole working demo you could follow, and no need use Upsert HttpGet action:
@model IEnumerable<Category>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Categories Data</h5>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Upsert", "Category")" class="btn btn-primary" style="box-shadow: none" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#categoryModal">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> &nbsp;Add Category
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- Modal for Create/Update Category -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="categoryModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="categoryModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" method="post">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="categoryModalLabel">
                                @if (TempData["CategoryId"] != null)
                                {
                                    <span>Edit Category</span>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span>Add New Category</span>
                                }
                            </h5>
                            <button type="button" style="box-shadow: none" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!-- Hidden Field for Id -->
                            <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="@(TempData["CategoryId"] ?? Guid.Empty.ToString())" />


                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="CategoryName" class="form-label fw-bold ms-1">Category Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CategoryName" name="CategoryName"
                                       value="@TempData["CategoryName"]" required placeholder="Category Name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th>S/N</th>
                        <th>Category Name</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{
                        int index = 1;
                    }

                    @foreach (var category in Model)
                    {

                        <!-- Modal for Create/Update Category -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="categoryModal_@index" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="categoryModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <form asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" method="post">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="categoryModalLabel">
                                                @if (TempData["CategoryId"] != null)
                                                {
                                                    <span>Edit Category</span>
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    <span>Add New Category</span>
                                                }
                                            </h5>
                                            <button type="button" style="box-shadow: none" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <!-- Hidden Field for Id -->
                                            <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="@category.Id" />


                                            <div class="mb-3">
                                                <label for="CategoryName" class="form-label fw-bold ms-1">Category Name</label>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CategoryName" name="CategoryName"
                                                       value="@category.CategoryName" required placeholder="Category Name" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@index</td>
                            <td>@category.CategoryName</td>
                            <td>@category.CreatedAt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Upsert", "Category", new { id = category.Id })"
                                   class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#categoryModal_@index">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        index++;
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

UPDATE:
The second way, you can use partial view to reuse the modal and use ajax to invoke Upsert HttpGet action and render the partial view.
1.make the modal html as a partial view named _ModalPartial.cshtml which locates in Views/Shared folder
       <!-- Modal for Create/Update Category -->
<div class="modal fade" id="categoryModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="categoryModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form asp-controller="Category" asp-action="Upsert" method="post">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="categoryModalLabel">
                        @if (TempData["CategoryId"] != null)
                        {
                            <span>Edit Category</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span>Add New Category</span>
                        }
                    </h5>
                    <button type="button" style="box-shadow: none" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <!-- Hidden Field for Id -->
                    <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="@(TempData["CategoryId"] ?? Guid.Empty.ToString())" />


                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="CategoryName" class="form-label fw-bold ms-1">Category Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CategoryName" name="CategoryName"
                               value="@TempData["CategoryName"]" required placeholder="Category Name" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Dismiss</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

2.Add the js in you main view
@model IEnumerable<Category>
<div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h5 class="mb-0">Categories Data</h5>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Upsert", "Category")" class="btn btn-primary" style="box-shadow: none">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> &nbsp;Add Category
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th>S/N</th>
                        <th>Category Name</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @{
                        int index = 1;
                    }
                    @foreach (var category in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@index</td>
                            <td>@category.CategoryName</td>
                            <td>@category.CreatedAt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Upsert", "Category", new { id = category.Id })"
                                   class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        index++;
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="loadModal">
    <!--load the partial-->
</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
         $("a").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();  // Prevent the default navigation

            var hrefValue = $(this).attr("href");  // Get the href value
            console.log('Clicked link href:', hrefValue);

            // Call the AJAX function
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: hrefValue,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#loadModal').empty();    //clear the previous modal 
                    $("#loadModal").html(data);   
                    $('#categoryModal').modal('show')    
                }
            })
        });           
    </script>
}

3.change your Upsert HttpGet action to return the partial view html as the response
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Upsert(Guid? id)
{
    Category category = new Category();

    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        category = _context.Category.Where(c => c.Id == id.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        if (category == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    // Store the retrieved category or new category in TempData
    TempData["CategoryId"] = category.Id;
    TempData["CategoryName"] = category.CategoryName;

    return PartialView("_ModalPartial");
}

